# What is the usage for # . > and space in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What are the different usages for the `#`, `.`, and `>` symbols and what do they reference?

For example, I know these two:

```
div#id {}     // <div id="id" />
div.class {}  // <div class="class" />
```

However, there are others which I don't understand:

```
div#id element
div#id>element
div#id.class
div#id .class
div#id>element#id .class
```

Any insights?

Comment: -1 Please *at least look for* a tutorial/reference. [W3C: CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). All the details -- tutorial not include.

Comment: I did, but still do not understand. the result looks different on different browsers.

Comment: @Jake: IE6 for one does not support `>` at all. Otherwise these should be supported by all modern (and half-modern) browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock that is one life-saver. =)

Comment: @Jake: Oh hello fellow Singaporean!

Comment: @BlotClock HELLO! lols.. nice meeting you. haha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pst says, you should really read up more on your own. I'll add that you can experiment using Firebug or an online tool like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to see live results. But I understand not everyone combines ID and class selectors, and the fact that your selectors are so similar and bunched like that can be confusing, so here goes:

The `>` symbol is called the *child combinator*, and is different from whitespace (the *descendant combinator*) in that `>` only looks one level deep in the DOM hierarchy.

Compare the first two selectors:

- ```
  div#id element /* With a space */
  ```

  > Select an `element`
  >   which descends from (is contained anywhere within) a `div` of `id="id"`.

  Would match either of these:

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <element />
  </div>
  ```

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <div class="class">
          <element />
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- ```
  div#id>element /* With a > sign */
  ```

  > Select an `element`
  >   which is a child of (is contained directly within) a `div` of `id="id"`.

  Will only match this:

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <element />
  </div>
  ```

  But not this because there is an intermediate `div.class` occurring between `element` and `div#id`:

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <div class="class">
          <element />
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Because the space represents the descendant combinator, it's significant in CSS selector syntax (except when used between other combinators and simple selectors, e.g. `E > F` and `E>F` are the same).

Compare the next two selectors:

- ```
  div#id.class /* No spaces anywhere */
  ```

  > Select a `div` of both `id="id"` and `class="class"`.

  By omitting the space, you are chaining three things together:

  1. The element selector (`div`),
  2. The ID selector (`#id`), *and*
  3. The class selector (`.class`).

  Thus a single element must satisfy all three selectors in order to be targeted by its rule. In HTML, this means it has to have both attributes, like so: `<div id="id" class="class">`
- ```
  div#id .class /* With a space */
  ```

  > Select any element of `class="class"`
  >   which descends from a `div` of `id="id"`.

  Notice the whitespace separating `div#id` and `.class`. This means `.class` applies to a totally different element.

  Would match either of these:

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <p class="class"></p>
  </div>
  ```

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <div>
          <p class="class"></p>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

  But nothing here will be matched because there's no `.class` to look for within `div#id`:

  ```
  <div id="id">
      <element />
  </div>
  ```

  And not this either, for the same reason:

  ```
  <div id="id" class="class"></div>
  ```

The last selector just involves putting it all together:

- ```
  div#id>element#id .class
  ```

  Funnily enough, the corresponding HTML structure would be invalid because you can't have more than one element with the same ID, but anyway:

  > Select any element of `class="class"`
  >   which descends from an `element` of of `id="id"`
  >   which is a child of a `div` of of `id="id"`.

Answer (score 6):

- `#` selects an ID (`<div id="something"></div>` -> `#something`)
- `.` selects a class (`<div class="something"></div>` -> `.something`)
- `>` selects a child directly under a specific parent (`<div><p></p></div>` -> `div > p`)
- `<space>` selects descendants under the specified parent (`<div><p id="one"></p><p id="two"></p></div>` -> `div #one`

Comment: +1 for succinctness, but your fourth bullet point should say "descendants", as "children" always implies only one degree of separation.

Comment: They should really do something about code blocks missing the padding when occurring in lists... but yeah +1 for succinctness.